# Looking for Anime with a prince faking being mentally handicapped hiding a giant mech suit wreaking havoc

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

This is all I can remember.

There are four worlds whose people and technology were all swapped so humans ended up with high tech mech suits that they used to kill each other. There was a supposedly handicapped prince who faked being mentally handicapped and had a giant mech suit hidden underground that he eventually used to wreak havoc on earth.

The protagonist also had a suit and he saved the day. He was in love with a girl who was from another world and when he saved the day, all the people and technology from the different worlds were sent back to their original one causing the girl to leave him. She had colored hair and the final scene was her waking up somewhere with some children commenting on her hair.

There may or may not have been a reference to the protagonists scars in the shape of the constellation of orion on his body.

Any ideas? I've searched the internet for two years trying to find it.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I understand why you edited, but I think you may have changed the meaning. I don't know if there is a suitable, universally understood term. In the UK, 'learning difficulties' is used. Wikipedia suggests 'intellectual disability' is used in the US. I'm not sure enough of the best phrase to make the edit myself.

Comment: @Fruitbat me neither, but I was trying to practice damage control. If someone does have a better term please feel free to [edit].

Comment: My standpoint is, until we track down the anime, we won't know what the proper term is. Who knows, maybe the character acts like a right fruitcake, and the the word to use would have been, "fruitcake".

Comment: I used the word retarded here not because I think that it is A) universally accepted or B) nice to use but because that is how they referred to the prince in the anime. I think that intellectual disability is the correct term in the US.       Still no idea what anime it was.. Darn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Super Dimension Century Orguss 02](http://www.mahq.net/animation/orguss/orguss2/orguss2toc.htm)*, the prequel to *[Super Dimension Century Orguss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Dimension_Century_Orguss)*

[image: Anime cover]

From [a review of Episode 5](http://www.mahq.net/animation/orguss/orguss2/org2ep5.htm): "Destroyer"

> As they ride an elevator down, Perion tells Manning that he pretended for seven years to be mentally retarded so that Miran wouldn't assassinate him. However, on the private refuge of his small island, he discovered a massive Armor.

Some screenshots from the episode:
[image] [image]

Comment: Awesome! So the answer was checked and you've been upvoted! Dude, thank you. Seriously 2 years looking for this movie. You made me very happy. No I have to re watch it and hope it's as good as I remember

Comment: Not at all. :) I've never seen it myself, but I'm glad I could help. Goodness knows that enough people have helped me with my own queries... and welcome to the site!

Comment: If you've never seen it, how did you find it?

Comment: If I recall correctly, I searched for "anime prince mentally retarded mecha" and it brought up the review I have linked above. Sometimes, it just takes the right combination of keywords