# 2000s (or earlier) anime movie with a mech powered by holy men, and a bad guy killing his family while pretending to be an idiot

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I watched this on the Sci Fi Channel - SYFY UK about 15 years ago. It ended with a giant mech battle. The bad guys' mech was powered by holy men (that chanted to keep it working). The good guys' mech was linked to him and controlled by his mind.

Also the main villain in the giant mech, pretended to be an idiot at the beginning until he poisoned his family so he could become king.

Comment: So, early 2000s? Do you remember what network you watched this on?

Comment: The Sci Fi Channel - SYFY UK

Comment: I marked your question as a duplicate of the older one since they both have the same accepted answer. Please understand that this is not a censure of your answer, but merely a recognition that you're looking for the same work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible you're thinking of *Super Dimension Century Orguss 02* as in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116906/looking-for-anime-with-a-prince-faking-being-mentally-handicapped-hiding-a-giant/116957#116957)?

From [a review of Episode 5](https://www.mahq.net/animation/orguss/orguss2/org2ep5.htm): "Destroyer"

> As they ride an elevator down, Perion tells Manning that he pretended for seven years to be mentally retarded so that Miran wouldn't assassinate him. However, on the private refuge of his small island, he discovered a massive Armor.

The "holy men" were likely the monks, who did not power the "Armors", but did use their psychic powers to provide long-range scanning capability as per the [TVTropes article entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/SuperDimensionCenturyOrguss).

> Members of an order of monks are used by both the Rivilian and Zafrin militaries as the equivalents of both radar and long-range cameras, thanks to their mental abilities. However, they have a tendency of dying after overusing their powers. Nataruma has unusually strong powers as a part-Emaan, which the Zafrin military trained her to use so she could help operate their enormous Decimator.

Comment: I literally just googled the title you posted and found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmLfcHzOtvY