# Looking for an obscure mecha manga from the 90s or earlier

Tags: story-identification, manga, mecha

So I have a real challenge for the mecha manga/anime buffs around here. Here goes:

Way back in the mid 1990s, I borrowed a VHS tape from a schoolmate that was some kind of mecha anime. The only things I really remember about it are that it featured a robot character called "The Colonel", who said something along the lines of "your world has become entangled in our problems", that there was a human character called Karachi, and that it involved a subplot of a man who pretended to be mentally enfeebled in order to keep some sort of aristocratic woman from assassinating him. He later got rid of her and assumed power, and controlled a giant floating mecha without legs (a giant flying robot torso with arms basically) called "Libo" or something similar. One other scene I distinctly remember was that this aforementioned aristocratic woman went insane, was holding her dead infant son in her arms, convinced herself that the boy was still alive, and asked her terrified handmaidens to go get him something to drink.

This isn't much to go on, but if any of the above rings a bell, please let me know. I've been browsing mecha anime lists like crazy, but haven't been able to find anything so far.

Comment: I've marked this as a Duplicate, but that doesn't mean you have a bad question. We just like to group questions with identical answers together to make it easier to gather all of the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the mention of trying to appear less than mentally competent, I'm guessing *[Super Dimension Century Orguss 02](http://www.mahq.net/animation/orguss/orguss2/orguss2toc.htm)*, the prequel to *[Super Dimension Century Orguss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Dimension_Century_Orguss)*

[image: Anime cover]

From [a review of Episode 5](http://www.mahq.net/animation/orguss/orguss2/org2ep5.htm): "Destroyer"

> As they ride an elevator down, Perion tells Manning that he pretended for seven years to be mentally retarded so that Miran wouldn't assassinate him. However, on the private refuge of his small island, he discovered a massive Armor.

There is someone who is promoted to Colonel in the series, and watching a clip of the episode online, there is a "Minister Karachi" who encourages King Mendez to declare war. As depicted in Episode 5, Parion's 6-year-old half brother, Siflay, is poisoned, which is part of why he's hiding his capabilities. And yes, Miran holds him in her arms as he dies, sending the handmaidens off, albeit for a doctor.

I previously provided this as an answer to [Looking for Anime with a prince faking being mentally handicapped hiding a giant mech suit wreaking havoc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/116906/23243)

Comment: Fuzzy, based on what I read from the episode summaries of Super Dimension Century Orguss 02, I'd say there is high probability that this is actually it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent. I added a few more details from watching the 5th episode online.

Comment: Welcome to the site!